# Setting up mailboxes for all users in a group

Tags: server, email, imap

I have a group called `users`. It has many users.

Now I want every user in this group to have their own mailbox. So, for example, if `john` is such a user, then `john@myserver.com` is an e-mail address.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is  `users` a standard `/etc/group` entry?

Comment: What mail server software are you using / would you like to use?

Comment: Yes, `users` is in `etc/group`: `users:x:100:`. I'm using/like to use Postfix/Courier for this job.

Answer (score 1):

In a default postfix setup every mail to $USER@$HOSTNAME will be delivered to $USER. You don't need to set that up explicitly.

For a basic postfix setup this looks like a decent howto: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto